# Creating an iCloud email

Tags: icloud, email

I'm trying to create an iCloud email account. After following the steps and get to the end, I get a message that says "Problem Turning On Mail". It says to try again later, but I keep getting the same message. What do I do now?

Answer (score 3):

Lots of reasons why Apple doesn’t allow mail creation. Best bet is to ask Apple Support about your case specifically:

- https://support.apple.com/contact

Sometimes it’s because too many accounts were created from that device or location, sometimes it’s a conflict reserving the alias or address, sometimes it’s just that millions of requests across thousands of computers get stuck on the server side or break.

Support will know is the system is up or down or if you hit a specific roadblock.